# Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP

Tags: php, deprecated

Tenho uma página no WordPress que há algum tempo está toda em branco e só aparece o *favicon*.

Habilitei a exibição da mensagem de erro do PHP para saber o que estava acontecendo e me apareceu isso:

> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ModuleBanners has a deprecated constructor in /customers/b/6/0/donnacostura.com.br/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/module-banners/module_banners.php on line 17
>
> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ModuleServicos has a deprecated constructor in /customers/b/6/0/donnacostura.com.br/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/module-services/module_services.php on line 17
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/b/6/0/donnacostura.com.br/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/module-banners/module_banners.php:17) in /customers/b/6/0/donnacostura.com.br/httpd.www/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1198

Como resolver isto?

Comment: Qual seu nível de conhecimento em PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para começar, você precisa interpretar as mensagens de erro.

As duas primeiras mensagens dizem que o construtor utilizando o nome da classe será removido nas versões futuras do PHP. O objetivo é te preparar para as futuras atualizações do seu PHP.

**Exemplo (*depreciado*):**

```
class MinhaClasse
{
    public function MinhaClasse()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Como deve ficar:**

```
class MinhaClasse
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

---

A última mensagem diz que você não pode alterar o cabeçalho da requisição porque já foram geradas saídas para o usuário.

Você pode verificar essa alteração no cabeçalho no lugar informado pela mensagem do erro:

```
/customers/b/6/0/donnacostura.com.br/httpd.www/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1198
```

Provavelmente é um redirecionamento: `header('Location: ...');`.

E como a própria mensagem sugere, a primeira saída gerada foi em:

```
/customers/b/6/0/donnacostura.com.br/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/module-banners/module_banners.php:17
```

Repare que esta saída é a primeira mensagem. Assim que resolver o primeiro problema, seu site deve voltar ao normal. Caso não, ele vai apontar outras classes que devem ser revisadas ou novos erros/avisos no seu site.

---

@off Aconselho focar mais na interpretação dos erros. Como te mostrei, o próprio PHP já te entrega "de lambuja" onde estão e quais são os erros. Ainda que você não entenda alguns termos da mensagem, tente entendê-los fazendo buscas sobre tais. Isso faz parte da base do aprendizado em qualquer linguagem que você vá programar.