# mPdf 7 não funciona no servidor

Tags: php, mpdf

Oi,

Tenho em minha máquina o **mPdf v.7** que funciona normalmente, mas quando subi, está dando um erro que parece relacionado a métodos de chamadas depreciadas.

*Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; mPDF has a deprecated constructor in /home/meusite/public_html/pasta/mpdf7/mpdf.php on line 89*

A questão é que em minha máquina tenho o **PHP 7.3** e online é **7.1**, ou seja, meu PHP é mais atual e mesmo assim funciona normalmente.

Tentei:

```
public function __construct(mPDF $mpdf){ 
    $this->mpdf = $mpdf;
}
```

E deu outro erro, relacionado ao usar 'public'

Meu código que funciona offline:

```
<?php
include('mpdf7/mpdf.php');
ob_start();
?>

<html> ... </html>

<?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->allow_output_buffering = true;
    $mpdf->Output('documento.pdf', 'I');
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Amigo, dá uma olhada nesse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365140/deprecated-methods-with-the-same-name-as-their-class-will-not-be-constructors-i), talvez te ajude.

Comment: No link, explica que são para versões futuras do PHP, só que na minha máquina o PHP é mais atual do que no servidor online e mesmo assim funciona :(

Comment: [RESOLVIDO] Trata-se dos requerimentos do PHP que devem ser configurados no servidor, como descrito em: https://packagist.org/packages/mpdf/mpdf